# web & database relationship infrastructure

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, database-design, laravel-5.4

One of my new clients needs his collection of sport website redesigned/-developped.

The collection consists of the following:

- 1 country website
- 2 region websites
- 1 for each province (around 5 or 6)

My problem is the following:
Each website has it's own features/data like news posts, tournaments, region rankings...
but there are also common data between them, for example players, clubs, global rankings.

My question is the following:
How sghould I structure my database?

- One database for each website? and copy commonly data with each query?
- One database for all. and use some type/region field.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you could look at like a tenants solution, having its own database can have it benefits, but I think in this scenario it is overkill, and what if you maybe wanna use something from site 1 on site 2? (Don't know if that's gonna happen) But for example let's take the posts table

Posts:

- id
- Title
- Text
- province_id

Province:

- id
- name
- region

The province as I understand it is the "lowest" in the structure meaning, they are always under a region, correct? This way you can referer what posts to show at which province, then you have to either do a trait or a global scope, adding a where statement with the provice_id. Try searching for some tenants guides, there are plenty out there showing how to do this.

Reading the post again a province might not be under a region? The Same concept applies though, just use another name than province, and maybe add a flag to tell if it's a province or region if you need that information